# Erase all data from Expo React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I would like to delete all data from my react native app based on Expo. The goal is to delete the data via a button in the application, as one could do by deleting the data in the Android settings.

I have already documented on AsyncStorage but when I delete the data, there are never any keys saved. I tried redirecting all my webview storage into the AsyncStorage, but it doesn't change anything.

Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **you can programmatically delete data from your React Native app** using Expo by utilizing the `AsyncStorage` API. However, it's important to note that the `AsyncStorage` API is asynchronous, so you need to handle the promises appropriately.

To delete all the data stored in `AsyncStorage`, you can use the `multiRemove` method. Try to use that:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Function to delete all data from AsyncStorage
const deleteAllData = async () => {
  try {
    const allKeys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys(); // Get all keys from AsyncStorage
    await AsyncStorage.multiRemove(allKeys); // Remove all keys

    // Display a success message or perform any other actions
    console.log('All data deleted successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    console.log('Error deleting data:', error);
  }
};

// Usage example
deleteAllData();
```

Remember to install the `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` package **in your project**.

```
expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

---

When you remove an item from `AsyncStorage` using the `removeItem` method, **it should delete the specific key-value pair from storage**, and the value associated with that key **should no longer be accessible**.

If you are observing that the amount of storage allocated to your application **remains the same after removing items** from `AsyncStorage`, it could be due to a few reasons:

- **Data is stored elsewhere:** AsyncStorage may be using a different storage mechanism or location on the device than what is visible in the application's allocated storage.
- **Caching or temporary storage:** It's possible that the storage you're seeing allocated to the application is being used for caching or temporary storage purposes by the operating system or other components of your app.
- **Other data sources:** Your application may be using additional data sources or storage mechanisms apart from AsyncStorage.

Comment: Thx traizooo, when you use AsyncStorage, how the data is saved in this storage? I've to review the whole code to control the save of data in it ? Or this remove method will erase the whole data app ?

Comment: When you use AsyncStorage, the data is typically saved on the device's disk in a location specific to the operating system. The exact storage mechanism used by AsyncStorage can vary depending on the platform and version of React Native you are using. Earlier versions of React Native used SQLite as the underlying storage mechanism, while newer versions may use other methods.

Comment: I mean, when I remove the AsyncStorage I see that the amount of Mb  in the parameter of the application allocated to the data is still the same. Moreover when I try to display on the console the key erased, there is nothing. It's like the AsyncStorage is empty of any data. However, the amount of data is still increasing in my app. It's like there's an other management of the data. Don't know if I'm clear in my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

> Asyncstorage.clear()

It will clear everything.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this function but as I said, it seems that my app keep data in other space. How can I redirect all the data storage to the AsyncStorage ?

Here my App.js code, I tried to wrap my entire app in the AsyncStorage but my app gets stuck on my splasher. I have the impression that she can't verify my tokens.

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Animator = createStackNavigator();
const AnimatorStack = () => {
    return (
        <Animator.Navigator initialRouteName="List" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            <Animator.Screen name="List" component={AnimatorListScreen} />
            <Animator.Screen name="Broadcast" component={BroadcastScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Animator.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Animator.Navigator>
    )
}

const Entrant = createStackNavigator();
const EntrantStack = () => {
    return (
        <Entrant.Navigator initialRouteName="Enter" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            <Entrant.Screen name="Enter" component={EntrantScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Entrant.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Entrant.Navigator>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({loading: true});
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState({language: null});

    useEffect(() => {
        const restoreInfos = async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            const userType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userType');
            setAuthState({loading: false, token, userType});
        };

        const restoreLanguage = async () => {
            const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
            setUserState({language});
        };

        restoreInfos();
        restoreLanguage();
    }, []);

    return (
        (authState.loading || !userState.language) ?
            // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} /> :
            <GlobalizeProvider ref={globalizeRef} locale={userState.language}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        {(authState.token == null || authState.userType == null) ?
                            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} /> :
                            authState.userType === 'showman' ?
                                <Stack.Screen name="Showman" component={AnimatorStack} options={{ headerShown: false }} /> :
                                <Stack.Screen name="Entrant" component={EntrantStack} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                        }
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </GlobalizeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your help